# 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, android, windows, keytool, signed-apk

I've created a small Android application using Ionic and I was going to build the signed apk to test the app.

When I typed 'keytool' command in my command prompt I'm getting this error

**'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

And I tried googling and all solved problems mentions that it's a problem with Path variable of JDK.
I tried changing my **'JAVA_HOME'** variable value to *'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin'* and to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin' and still getting the same error.

But when I run the 'keytool' command it the cmd *'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin'* location, it works.

Can anyone help me with this ? What might be a problem that I can't access it globally ?

Comment: The problem is that the bin directory is not on your %PATH%.  The command shell (e.g. "cmd.exe") looks for commands in the search path given by %PATH%.

Comment: Thanks. But how to add the bin directory to %PATH% ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That happens because you haven't added the *bin* directory of your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in your `%PATH%`.

1. Add the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` with path *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131* without the *bin* directory.
2. Add the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` directory at the end of your `%PATH%`.

Comment: Thanks. As you've mentioned I changed JAVA_HOME  variable path to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131'  But I don't get the 2nd point

Comment: @ThidasaParanavitharana You have also a variable named `Path`. You can find inside it, some paths to executable. At the end of these paths, you have to add the last path with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked

Comment: @ThidasaParanavitharana No problem. If it worked, mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Perfect explanation. Just what I needed. Thanks a lot!