# Why expo fetch:android:hashes does not work

Tags: android, hash, fetch, expo, keytool

1. SDK Version: 35
2. Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android

expo diagnostics

```
Expo CLI 3.4.1 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10
    Binaries:
      Yarn: 1.17.3 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
      npm: 6.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
```

app.json

```
  "expo": {
    "name": "App Name",
    "slug": "app-name",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "35.0.0",
    "scheme": "app-name",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "default",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "ru.name.app.my",
      "config": {
        "googleSignIn": {
          "reservedClientId": "key"
        }
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "ru.name.app.android",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Hello. After building the application, google maps and google authorization stopped working.
I came across this instruction to fix my problem - https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/#deploying-to-a-standalone-app-on-android
But I can’t go beyond step 6 - "6. Run expo fetch:android:hashes".
I am facing an error:

```
Are you sure you have keytool installed?
keytool is a part of OpenJDK: https://openjdk.java.net/
Also make sure that keytool is in your PATH after installation.
"keytool" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

spawn keytool ENOENT
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUJZc.png)

Java is installed on my computer. Tell me, what am I doing wrong? I call the command "expo fetch:android:hashes" after "expo start", from the directory of my project.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/354

Comment: I saw this manual, but it didn’t help me (I don’t understand where I have to start "expo fetch:android:hashes" for it to work. I started from the directory C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk \ bin, but it didn’t work, I started from the folder of my project, it also didn’t work.

Comment: Add to path variables of windows

Comment: Please, tell me how?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720147/keytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: After that close console and open new one